# Riddle on the rocks

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My beginning is slang for a dollar.
My middle can describe beer.
My end is circular.
What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> **CLAMBERING**!

*My beginning is slang for a dollar.*

> **CLAM** is a slang term for a dollar.

*My middle can describe beer.*

> A pleasantly coloured pint of beer is a pint of **AMBER** (the 'amber nectar').

*My end is circular.*

> 'Clambering' ends in **RING** - something which is round in shape.

This makes sense of the title too, since:

> Clambering is something you would physically do *on the rocks* (or over them).

Comment: And of course... [ROT13] "Pynzorevat" zrnaf "pyvzo be zbir va na njxjneq naq ynobevbhf jnl" - nf lbh jbhyq "ba ebpxf" (gur chmmyr'f gvgyr)

Comment: @Astralbee Ha! I think your comment crossed with my edit! :)

Comment: @Stiv I was about to post more clues to this puzzle, when I saw that you solved it. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Buckroll

My beginning is slang for a dollar.

> Buck

My middle can describe beer.

> Kro (common short for Kronenbourg)

My end is circular.

> Roll

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Benjamino ?

My beginning is slang for a dollar.

> Benjamins are a slang for dollar

My middle can describe beer.

> [Jamin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PQTSV92) is a beer brand (I guess anyone can name a beer after themselves)

My end is circular.

> ends with `O` which is circular